# case when sum ( condition )= sum (condition) and condition then using db2 system database

Tags: syntax, db2, sum, case

Good night, I am working in DB2 and I have been having some troubles making a query with case when 
I have to find a way to make a query to define if a record of some category is valid only if the required fields of the relation are required and have been marked as selected, but in this case some registrys are empty and then I must exclude, I have a query like this:

```
 Select (case (sum(category_id) where required='true' and selected='true') = sum(category_id) where required='true' then 'Yes'
     else 'no'
    from category_table
```

The problem, is that in some category the required field are all false (it's means do not exist) then I must put a condition like the sum equal to cero, but i always get a syntax error. I have something like this,

```
 Select (case (sum(category_id) where required='true' and selected='true') = sum(category_id) where required='true' and (count(category_id) where required='true' != 0 ) then 'Yes'
     else 'no'
    from category_table
```

I have this problem in db2, saddly I can not put the original query hear because the proxy of my work don't le me pass emails to outside or even login at the web page from there.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: That query isn't valid syntax (`WHEN` is missing, `WHERE` is not valid there), but probably isn't going to work anyways (`SUM(...)` is an aggregate function, but the system won't know which rows to use for `required`/`selected`).  Summing something called `category_id` sounds like the wrong thing to do (the value of an id should be considered meaningless).  Can you give sample starting data and the results you expect to see based on that?  I'm having trouble figuring out what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the VALUE function? if no rows will qualify the case conditions then you'll get Zero in the result.

Comment: `VALUE(...)` is a DB2 synonym for `COALESCE(...)`, and will end up performing identically to a `CASE` statement.  It doesn't magically add some default value; it picks the first operand in the list that isn't null, and returns null if no non-null arguments have been specified.  The OP is getting a **syntax error**, which won't really be effected.  I'm not sure this solves the OP's problem anyways.